# How to undefine a macro in configure.ac

Tags: autoconf

I am writing my `configure.ac` script, and have a few custom enable arguments which define macros in my C code if enabled.  An example:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([example],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-example], [This is an example]))
AS_IF([test "x$enable_example" = "xyes"], [
      AC_DEFINE(EXAMPLE_MACRO, 1, [This is a definition example])
      ])
```

Now say I have an enable option which, if enabled, must disable the effects of `--enable-example` option.  I have the normal setup:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([another-feature],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--another-feature], [This is a feature which enables something, but disables --enable-example]))
AS_IF([test "x$enable_another_feature" = "xyes"], [
      AC_DEFINE(ANOTHER_FEATURE_MACRO, 1, [This is another feature definition])
      ])
```

Now I need to be able to undefine the `EXAMPLE_MACRO` macro, but I can't find anything to undo the `AC_DEFINE`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply delay the `AC_DEFINE` function calls? Note, I'm not a big fan of the `AS_IF` macro...

```
if test "x$enable_another_feature" = xyes ; then
  # enable_example="no" # (optional)
  AC_DEFINE([ANOTHER_FEATURE_MACRO], [1])
elif test "x$enable_example" = xyes ; then
  AC_DEFINE([EXAMPLE_MACRO], [1])
fi
```

If the `AC_DEFINE` is not executed, the corresponding `#define ...` is *not* instantiated in the config header. Discussed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Header-Templates).

Answer (score 0):

In case of boolean type symbols like in your example, where you simply enable flag or disable, all you need is another call to AC_DEFINE to disable the symbol:

```
AC_DEFINE(EXAMPLE_MACRO, 0)
```

The symbol will still exist, but with the new value of 0 (boolean false).

Update:
To complete the answer, the usual way you do it if there are conflicting options specified is termination with error during compilation. When you define a symbol, and config.h.in contains the #undef EXAMPLE_MACRO, the AC_DEFINE will turn it around into #define EXAMPLE_MACRO. So you have two options to work with such a macro, check if its value is set to 1/0 or do a check for both macros set and assert if they are.